# Undefined index error in ajax using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am sending data through ajax it is working properly using jquery but JavaScript code is giving undefined error

```
function send_message() {
  var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
  var mobile = document.querySelector("#mobile").value;
  var message = document.querySelector("#message").value;

  if (name == "") {
    alert('Please enter name');
  } else if (email == "") {
    alert('Please enter email');
  }
  else if (mobile == "") {
    alert('Please enter mobile');
  }
  else if (message == "") {
    alert('Please enter message');
  } else {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "send_message.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Response
        var response = this.responseText;
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
      }
    };
    var data = 'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&mobile='+mobile+'&message='+message;
   ajax.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
}
```

the error code is

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\webmakeup\send_message.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\webmakeup
```

send_message.php is the file I am sending data to.
This is my php code

```
require('connection.inc.php');
require('functions.inc.php');
$name=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['name']);
$email=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['email']);
$mobile=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['mobile']);
$comment=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['message']);
$added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
mysqli_query($con,"insert into contact_us(name,email,mobile,comment,added_on) values('$name','$email','$mobile','$comment','$added_on')");
echo "Thank you";
?>
```

Comment: Show your PHP. PHP can't parse JSON into `$_POST` variables. So either send URL-encoded data, `FormData`, or use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input", true))` in PHP.

Comment: That's not how you do JSON, are you sure that you are supposed to be sending JSON.

Comment: added the php code kindly please wrote the code so that I wont get the error

Comment: I am beginner to JSON and ajax donot know how to send the data received from input so I used JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP endpoint is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data not JSON.
You can use a URLSearchParams object to send that type of data.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "send_message.php", true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // Response
    var response = this.responseText;
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);
  }
};
var data = new URLSearchParams ({name,email,mobile,message});
ajax.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't JSON.stringify what you send.
Wrap each variable in encodeUriComponent.
Don't add a space after the equals.

Try:

```
var data = 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(name)
 + '&email=' + encodeURIComponent(email)
 + '&mobile=' + encodeURIComponent(mobile)
 + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message);

ajax.send(data);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: encodeUriComponent is not defined

Comment: Sorry I mis-capitalized encodeURIComponent